# Angular $http.get doesn't return what i expected

Tags: php, webserver

I'm trying to do a simple http get request but it doesn't return what i expected.

Here is the code

.js :

```
$http.get("database.php").success(function(data, status)
{
    alert(data);
    $scope.data = data;
}
).error(function(data, status)
{
    $scope.untruc = "Error";
});
```

.php :

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

$conn = // my connection

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error)
    echo "Connection failed";
else
{
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM user";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

?>

and the ouput is :

```
data : <?php header('Content-type: application/json'); $conn = // my connection; // Check connection    if ($conn->connect_error) echo "Connection failed"; else { $sql = "SELECT id FROM user"; $result = $conn->query($sql); echo json_encode($result); } ?>
```

literaly the code...

I'm expecting it to get the $result. Do you know how i could do that ?

Comment: Most likely a misconfigured webserver that does not pass the PHP files through the PHP interpreter

Comment: Is PHP installed on your server? For some reason your .php file isn't being handled as it should and returns the PHP code in plain text.

Comment: I just realised i wasn't testing it on a server but on local...
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check you php code once.
And try to implement this code

```js
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'database');

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error)
    echo "Connection failed";
else
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $myresult = [];
    $i =0;
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
  $myresult[$i] = $row;
  $i++;
 }
    
    //echo "<pre>";
    echo json_encode($myresult);
}

?>
```